# Google Form Submit > Attach New Responses to Email and Send

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a script that turns a submitted form into a PDF and emails it automatically but I can't seem to get my head around if it is possible to implement a function i would like: -

1. User fills in Google form
2. Submits form
3. This creates entirely new spreadsheet based on same headers from the form
4. Emails thie spreadsheet as an .xlsx attachment automatically to a specific email address

Is this possible? I feel like I am missing a simple way to do this but I am having a moment of noobishness! :-)

Answer (score 0):

1, 2, 3 - all quite possible.

4 - Not as such. There's no support in Google Apps Script for converting a Sheet to Excel format. However you could produce a CSV file which would be understood by Excel or any other spreadsheet program, and email that as an attachment.

Generating a CSV is covered in one of the Apps Script tutorials. See [Saving a selected Range to a CSV file](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) from ***Tutorial: Interacting With Your Docs List***.

An example of attaching files from Drive is provided in the documentation for [MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29).