# Attempting to Attach a CSV, Converting to PDF

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, email-attachments

I have a code where I am attempting to attach a CSV saved in Drive (automatically replaced) to an email. At the moment, I can get it to add using fileBlob - DriveApp.getFileById(...).getBlob() but, it's attaching as a PDF.

Per Mogsdad's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251169/google-form-submit-attach-new-responses-to-email-and-send/20274055#20274055) there is a way to attach a CSV, but looking through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail%28String,String,String,Object%29) I can't seem to find anything that will allow using a CSV. In fact, according to the [documentation for getAS()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source) it literally says: "For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option. For images in BMP, GIF, JPEG, or PNG format, any of 'image/bmp', 'image/gif', 'image/jpeg', or 'image/png' are also valid."

Does this mean in is impossible to attach a CSV (or, really, anything other than PDF) from Drive to an email using Apps Scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the CSV file is in your Drive, you can use this snippet to attach it to an email.

```
function sendCSV() {
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(FILE_ID).getBlob();
  MailApp.sendEmail("email@example.com", "Subject", "CSV", {attachments:[blob]});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per following Google Documentation: -

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source.html

Following is mentioned: -

**For most blobs, 'application/pdf' is the only valid option.**

Following expected work-around: -

```
https://gist.github.com/nirajkadam/0b41a01b8e739800c964
```